# Look in between, what am I?

Tags: riddle, poetry

I have created this poetic puzzle, where you need to give me one word that I am looking for.

> *You thought you could attack me.
>
>   But hold on, not so fast.
>
>   Look in between,
>
>   since German trains are best.
>
>   No matter black or white,
>
>   if you did not consider,
>
>   You might've been winning,
>
>   But now I am the winner.*

**What happened here?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> zwischenzug (Chess & Draughts) chess a tactical move interpolated into an exchange or series of exchanges to improve the outcome [German: in-between move]
> based on Rubios answer and your hint about the 'look in between' (also dazwischen) line?

You thought you could attack me.
But hold on, not so fast.
Look in between,

> in between means "dazwischen" in German (=zwischen)

since German trains are best.

> train means "Zug" in German (=zug)

No matter black or white,

> hints at the solution having to do with chess.

if you did not consider,

> my move is meant to look like it is totally obsolete while significantly changing the outcome.

You might've been winning,
But now I am the winner.

> since you didn't consider my move to be important in any way you now have lost.

Big thanks to @Rubio your guess helped a lot.

Comment: You've got it! If you could explain it line to line (like Rubio did), that would be a good answer.

Comment: @BlueRineS editet my answer to explain my answer in more detail in relation to your riddle.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from where other people have gone, I offer:

> In **[zugswang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang)**, or a forced-move situation.

The entire poem conveys a theme of

> chess, where it seems one player has an advantage, but where something missed changes the outcome from a win to a loss.  In chess, *zugzwang* describes a scenario where one player would prefer to pass but cannot (as passing is not an option), leaving them having to make a move in a position where any move they might make can only serve to make their position worse.  Wikipedia notes that "the term is also used in combinatorial game theory, where it means that it directly changes the outcome of the game from a win to a loss"—directly the theme conveyed in the poem.

In particular,

> `since German trains are best.`
>  is suggestive; the German word for train is **Zug**.

The last lines:

> No matter black or white,
>   if you did not consider,
>   You might've been winning,
>   But now I am the winner.

> make pretty plain the idea of either player facing a loss in what should be a winning position, which can definitely happen to a player put in zugzwang.

Comment: You are unbelievably close, but it's still a different word (perhaps in a similar theme as your suggestion). I think you can solve it, when I say that the word is quite literally related to the 'in between' line. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are referring to the:

> Chess Train that runs through Germany each year...

This year there was a guy:

> who challenged the grand master on the train and lost...surprise!

Soooooo......

> the compound word would be "Checkmate" !!

Comment: The answer is not what I thought. In one aspect, you are close though. I am looking for a single (compound) noun.

Comment: I modified my answer to include what seems to be an obvious answer

Comment: Think differently: each of my lines is connected to the meaning of the word in some way. Your answer is invariant to German trains.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dr T's suggestions, is the answer:

> Stalemate?

You thought you could attack me. But hold on, not so fast.

> During a stalemate no one can move regardless of whos turn it is

Look in between, since German trains are best.

> Unsure. Possibly referring to the stalemate in the German trenches of World War One?

No matter black or white, if you did not consider, You might've been winning, But now I am the winner.

> No matter how many more pieces black or white has on the board, if they accidentally allow a stalemate, it is a draw, and their opponent escapes defeat

Comment: We're getting closer and closer. Your suggestion is not right still, unfortunately. The 'look in between' is actually the closest  indication of the word I am looking for. the 'Germain train' is intrinsically related to word, but not strictly related to the meaning. Try again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is based entirely off the work of all others, but could it be as simple from here as the term

> "railroad"?

Comment: Nope. Rubio was closest.